# Is IPMulticast possible in Dart?

Tags: dart

I have some scenarios where I would like to connect a Dart (server side) client to a Java IPmulticasting server.  I couldn't see how to configure the Dart socket for the multicast scenario.  Is this possible?

Thanks

PM

Comment: Looks like issue http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=1975 has it covered for later.
PM

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the question!

The dart:io library (docs here: http://api.dartlang.org/docs/continuous/dart_io.html) contains the server-side (aka command-line) networking capabilities.

As of today, only TCP sockets are supported.

Please star [issue 1975](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=1975) to express support for UDP sockets.